# Invalid conversion from int** to const int**

Tags: c++, constants, implicit-conversion, multiple-indirection

I have a class with a 2D array of ints implemented as an int**. I implemented an accessor function to this 2D array as follows, returning a const int** to prevent the user from being able to edit it:

```
const int** Class::Access() const
{
     return pp_array;
}
```

But I got the compilation error "invalid conversion from int** to const int**". Why is a promotion to const not allowed here? How can I give the user access to the information without editing rights?

Comment: Note: your variable names cannot begin with numbers.

Comment: Right, it doesn't actually in the code, that's just an oversight by me in generalising the names - edited out now :)

Comment: A Matrix class encapsulating a 1D vector would work really well for holding the data too. Much better than a 2D pointer array. It also eliminates confusion such as this.

Comment: are you also getting the '...discards qualifiers...' error message?

Comment: I haven't learned about vectors yet unfortunately...

Comment: @AdityaKumar - No I'm only getting the one error message

Comment: Always a good time to start. The syntax is, for the most part, identical to arrays, with better support for being passed around from function to function. They also include out-of-bounds checking if you use `at` instead of `[]`.

Comment: This must have been covered by a prior question, it's a very common problem.

Comment: @Mark: Probably, but if there is an existing question, it's not tagged well.  There are no other questions with `const` and `multiple-indirection`.

Comment: @Mark: Ok, I found one, but it's about C, and the only relevance to this case is in linked websites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was mistaken about the `const`ness of the method being the reason for the error. As Ben points out, the `const`-ness of the method is irrelavent, since that applies only to the value of the exterior pointer [to pointers to `int`s], which can be copied to a mutable version trivially.

In order to protect the data (which is your preferred outcome) you should make both the `int`s and the pointers to `int`s constant:

```
int const * const * Class::Access() const
{
   return pp_array;
}
```

Will work.

If you prefer to have the const in front you can also write the declaration like so:

```
const int * const * Class::Access() const;
```

but since the second `const` applies to the pointers, it must be placed to the right (like the `const` which applies to the method) of the asterisk.

Comment: why has the const been removed from before the int? is the data pointed to still constant here?

Comment: @BugalugsNash, read it right to left. The int is still const. However, if there's nothing to the left of the const, it applies to the right.

Comment: const before/after int are the same. It changes meaning when displaced relative to the '*' symbol

Comment: I wrote another post about how const works, you can move the first const in front of the int with the same effect, though it gets a bit confusing when switching locations in mid-statement.

Comment: @AdityaKumar Except that the 'consts' must go _after_ the pointer's stars; so I wrote it that way to be consistent.

Comment: This should be useful for reading things: http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html.

Comment: @BugalugsNash: I just finished typing my own answer.

Comment: @BenVoigt *facepalm* Yes, I see which reasoning you mean now. I'll edit.

Answer (score 7):

Greyson is correct that you'll want to use `const int* const*`, but didn't explain why your original version failed.

Here is a demonstration of *why* `int**` is incompatible with `const int**`:

```
const int ci = 0;
const int* pci = &ci;
int* pi;
int** ppi = &pi;
const int** ppci = ppi; // this line is the lynchpin
*ppci = pci;
*pi = 1; // modifies ci!
```

Comment: While this is correct, it does not address the reason that the int** needs to be const in this instance; The 'const'ness of the method is why returning the mutable pointers to pointers to ints is the key.

Comment: @Greyson: The `const`-ness of the method makes no difference, no one is writing `pp_array = anything`.  The new wording I just added is an explanation why your reasoning was totally wrong.

Comment: Without the `const`-ness of the method the return specification of `int const **` is fine, though.

Comment: @Greyson: With a `const` method, a return specification of `int**` is still fine.  I explained why.  However, he wanted to return a read-only pointer, i.e. `int const **`, but `const` must be added from the outside in.  Also, did you even read the warning message?

Comment: I'm a little confused - I see what you're saying is that int** cannot convert to const int** because it messes with the const-ness of the int being pointed to. But in your code, at what point does it say that pi points to ci?

Comment: @BugalugsNash: The second-to-last line writes into `pi` for the first time, storing `&ci` (the value inside `pci`).

Comment: @Greyson and Ben - to test what you're saying I removed the const from the original method and was receiving the same error - invalid conversion from int** to const int**

Comment: @BugalugsNash: I already said that the `const` on the method doesn't matter (My first comment to this answer).

Comment: There seemed to be an argument about it, I thought I'd let you both know what the compiler said.